# Vagrant: syncing folder /var/cache/apt

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, mount, apt

I want to run some tests with apt-get install ... on a Ubuntu+Vagrant machine
and I want to store the /var/cache/apt folder on the host machine to prevent repeating downloads from ubuntu.com

So I added the line

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/home/egon/DummyPackages/apt", "/var/cache/apt",
    user: "root", group: "root"
```

to the Vagrantfile.

But then `apt-get install` does not work anymore, I always get this error:

```
E: Dynamic MMap ran out of room. Please increase the size of APT::Cache-Start. Current value: 25165824. (man 5 apt.conf)
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Dynamic MMap ran out of room. Please increase the size of APT::Cache-Start. Current value: 25165824. (man 5 apt.conf)
E: Error occurred while processing xplanet-images (NewVersion2)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists /us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_vivid_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I've detected, the access rights of the pkgcache will be overriden.

before `apt-get`:

```
-rw-r--rw- 1 egon egon 25178732 Nov 11 11:31 pkgcache.bin
```

after:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 egon egon 25178732 Nov 11 11:44 pkgcache.bin
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: [It has been suggested](https://gist.github.com/juanje/3797297#gistcomment-1620149) to use `~/.cache/apt` on your host.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to make the `sync_folder` as

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/home/egon/DummyPackages/apt", "/var/cache/apt",
user: "root", group: "root", mount_options: ["dmode=777, fmode=646"]
```

This mount the folder with directory mode as 777 and files mode as 646.
You can adjust the values for your own needs

Answer (score -1):

While not the answer to your question, I hopefully have the solution for your problem :-)

As your problem is pretty common, there is a nice plugin for this: [vagrant-cachier](https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-cachier). This will cache several types of repository-like data (yum, apt, gems, ...) in so called *buckets* that are stored in your host's `~/.vagrant.d/cache/` folder. See the [usage guide](http://fgrehm.viewdocs.io/vagrant-cachier/usage/).

Comment: That project is unmaintained and has been archived on GitHub.